# How to update object inside a list based on another list of object

Tags: c#, .net

I have two lists below:

```
var listA = new List<CompanyContact>(listAItems);
var listB = new List<CompanyContactDto>(listBItems);

public class CompanyContact
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string ContactId { get; set; }

        public bool IsMainContact { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

public class CompanyContactDto
    {
        public string CompanyId { get; set; }
        public string ContactId { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastSavedDateTime { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I want to copy the email property from list B to list A where contactId is the same in both lists.

```
var contacts = mapper.Map(listA, listA);
```

But it's nulling the other items.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried automapper. I updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
var aLookup = listA.ToLookup(a => a.ContactId);

foreach (var b in listB)
{
   foreach(var a in aLookup[b.ContactId])
   {
       a.Email = b.Email;
   }
}
```

Or, with less code,

```
foreach ((var a, var b) in aList.Join(
                                    bList,
                                    a => a.ContactId,
                                    b => b.ContactId,
                                    (a, b) => (a, b)))
{
    a.Email = b.Email;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var companyContactDto in listB)
{
    var matchingContacts = listA.Where(c => c.ContactId == companyContactDto.ContactId);
    
    foreach (var companyContact in matchingContacts)
    {
        companyContact.Email = companyContactDto.Email;
    }
}
```

With Dictionary for enumerating `listA` only once:

```
var contactsByContactId = listA.ToDictionary(c => c.ContactId);

foreach (var companyContactDto in listB)
{
    if (contactsByContactId.TryGetValue(companyContactDto.ContactId, out var matchingContact)
    {
        matchingContact.Email = companyContactDto.Email;
    }
}
```

Comment: `ToDictionary` will fail if there is more than one match.